# Can I set different colours for content contributed by different users in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way of assigning default colours for content contributed by different users in [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)?

For example, I would like to have content contributed by *user A* **green** by default, by *user B* **blue** by default etc.

Comment: The wikiwho API *might* be adaptable to your wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Revision contents do not distinguish between users, and so there is no way to style them differently. You need to use some kind of `blame` tool to extract the information what bits of content were contributed by which user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no lightweight solution to do that. For a heavy one, see [WikiTrust](http://wikitrust.soe.ucsc.edu/). It colors contributions based on a trust metric it computes, but can be probably tricked to use static colors.

It's quite complicated to install though, you probably don't want to bother with it unless you *really* need per-user colors.